# Pandas Merge on Specific Attributes of DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, merge

I currently have two pandas data frames which are both indexed using the pandas DateTimeIndex format.

```
df1 
datetimeindex         value
2014-01-01 00:00:00   204.501667
2014-01-01 01:00:00   125.345000
2014-01-01 02:00:00   119.660000

df2 (where the year 1900 is a filler year I added during import. Actual year does not matter)
datetimeindex         temperature
1900-01-01 00:00:00   48.2
1900-01-01 01:00:00   30.2
1900-01-01 02:00:00   42.8
```

I would like to use `pd.merge` to combine the data frames based on the left index, however, I would like to ignore the year altogether to yield this:

```
merged_df 
datetimeindex        value        temperature
2014-01-01 00:00:00  204.501667   48.2
2014-01-01 01:00:00  125.345000   30.2
2014-01-01 02:00:00  119.660000   42.8
```

so far I have tried:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on =
['df1.index.month','df1.index.day','df1,index.hour'],right_on = 
['df2.index.month','df2.index.day','df2.index.hour'],how = 'left')
```

which gave me the error `KeyError: 'df2.index.month'`

Is there a way to perform this merge as I have outlined it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to lose the quotesL

```
In [11]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=[df1.index.month, df1.index.day, df1.index.hour],
                            right_on=[df2.index.month, df2.index.day, df2.index.hour])
Out[11]:
   key_0  key_1  key_2       value  temperature
0      1      1      0  204.501667         48.2
1      1      1      1  125.345000         30.2
2      1      1      2  119.660000         42.8
```

*Here `"df2.index.month"` is a string whereas `df2.index.month` is the array of months.*

Comment: This works great! Would there be any way to make the new data frame have the same index as df1?

Comment: @enmyj you can set the index afterwards: `res.index = df1.index`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as efficient because pd.to_datetime can be slow:

```
df2['NewIndex'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df2['NewIndex'] = df2['NewIndex'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2014))
df2.set_index('NewIndex',inplace=True)
```

Then just do a merge on the whole index.